# How to append data to the element that launch method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a simple class to append a `content.html` file when `MyClass.display()` is called.

```
class MyClass
    @display: (display) ->
      $.get 'content.html', (data) ->
        $('body').append data
```

The code above always append the data to the end of the `body`.

The HTML code is simply this

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>text before</p>
    <script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      MyClass.display();
    </script>
    <p>text after</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering how it is possible to append the data just after the enclosing `</script>` tag that triggered the function. That would in between the `</script>` and the following `<p>` tag.

One requirement is that I should not modify the HTML markup. I can not add IDs  directly to markup as proposed in one of the answers below.

I know this is possible because I can see it in the Google AdSense code. But since their javascript code seems encrypted I can't decode how its done.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please add the code which triggers the function? Ideally including the event binding (if you are binding to an event).

Comment: You want to append `content.html` to the `<script>` or replace the `<script>` or go between the `<script>` and the `<p>text after</p>`?

Comment: `content.html` should be added immediately following the enclosing `</script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While javascript code is running, its containing script tag is the last element available in the DOM object

You can grab its reference for example like this,

```
var ele = $('script:last');
```

From there, depending on the content of `content.html` you can do the necessary work to place content *after* the script tag (not *append* inside the script tag, that'll not be what you're looking for)

e.g. If `content.html` has its own top level element, `p`

```
<p>
  <strong>hello</strong> world!
</p>
```

then you can simply

```
var MyClass = {
  display: function() {
    var ele = $('script:last');
    $.get('content.html', function(data) {
      ele.after(data);
    });
  }
}
```

**note 1:** you must get reference `ele` outside of the `$.get` callback. the callback runs asynchronously - by then the DOM would've likely loaded more elements and `script:last` may not be your script tag anymore.

**note 2:** if `content.html` does not contain a top level element that wraps the entire thing, then you'd have to wrap it yourself in the callback, e.g. `ele.after("<div class='my-own-wrapper'>" + data + "</div>");`

For reference: https://gist.github.com/4122339

Answer (score -1):

I see what you are trying to do. You want to insert HTML inside certain areas of markup.

I recommend you do something like this:

```
class MyClass
    @display: (display) ->
      $.get 'content.html', (data) ->
        document.write data
```

and

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>text before</p>
    <script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      MyClass.display();
    </script>
    <p>text after</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Its important that you have your script at the bottom of the page, so that the markup has a chance to load. Otherwise, your script might run before the page finishes loading.

Comment: A requirement is to do not add more markup than the pair of `<script>` tags.

Comment: you can just use document.write()

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: For some reason the document.write replaces the whole page area and not just place after the enclosing `</div>` as expected.

Comment: Sorry about that. In my local test, I was simply using document.write in the place where you have your function call. It turns out that if you put document.write inside a function, it will not run until the entire page has loaded. At that point, document.write behaves differently and will overwrite the entire page. The only way to do this with your requirements, is to know ahead of time, where you want to place the content like I had in my original answer of using a placeholder div, or to use the "after" or "before" jquery functions.